# Best software for local Contact/Calendar sync to Android?

Tags: software-recommendation, android, contacts, calendar

After 4 years on mac, I am switching back to Ubuntu. 
For OSX and for Windows there are tons of apps that sync your Contacts/Calendar to Android "cloud-less" over USB or Bluetooth like SyncMate, MyPhoneExplorer, MissingSync, etc.

I am looking for something that does the same on Ubuntu.

Thanks a lot for your suggestions !

Comment: Did you try syncevolution?

Comment: New on the scene: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/California (no Android version on the horizon yet, though)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, a linux solution for syncing your PIM data directly to an Android phone does not exist yet.
As I had a same problem, I found several possible "workarounds" without handing off your data to a 3rd party:

- Setting up your own "Owncloud" server on your local computer.
  Drawback: Server setup might be complicated. Owncloud Android apps seem to be still in beta. Phone and computer need to on the same network. May not viable when e.g. travelling a lot.

  Run MyPhoneExplorer in Wine.
  I found a detailed setup explanation in the MyPhoneExplorer Forum.
  Drawback: You will need to run Thunderbird/Lightning in Wine too.

  Stay on Win/Mac. At least till this functionality is present in Linux.

Answer (score 3):

After numerous tries, I recommend on Android side:
CalDav-sync
CardDav-sync

On Linux side:
radicale (radicale.org): for calendar and contacts.

I don't have a clean solution yet for file sync (maybe python-webdav on Linux)

Answer (score 1):

I have just started using the "Sync" app which can be found in the Ubuntu Software Centre from 12.04 onwards.    5 minutes after installing I was able to connect it to my Nokia E72 (Symbian) phone via bluetooth and sync all contacts.

I haven't tried it with an Android phone yet but if you have one it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

As far as calendars are concerned, I can recommend

[Rainlendar](http://www.rainlendar.net/cms/index.php)

It's easy to install, use and configure. Additionally, it offers fully functional synchronization for many online calendar services, e.g. Google Calendar, which would be the calendar synchronization option of choice when it comes to Android, wouldn't it?

I'm using Rainlendar since ms windows times and it never failed me. I'm using it to sync my android phone and ubuntu calendars every day. It's the best calendar application on linux I've been able to find so far.

If you want to synchronize calendars offline, as I suppose judging from your question, then you can e.g. download your calendar file as ics-file and import it to Rainlendar as well.

Comment: But to sync with Google calendar, you must buy a license. The free version doe not sync, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

In Gnome Online Accounts add the same google account that you use on your android device.